# Any loaded jquery slider plugin return this object has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider

So, here's the deal: i'm trying to implement a slider into the homepage of this site, and i've tryied NivoSlider but it kept saying that the Object had no methud such as nivoSlider.

So i gave up on it and now i'm trying to implement CCSlider, a paid slider (yes i bought it, so, no cracking :P), and now it's saying that the Object has no such method as ccslider.

I'm kinda lost! Here are the call for the scripts and the function to activate the slider:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_assets; ?>css/ccslider.css">

<script src="<?php echo $base_assets; ?>js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $base_assets; ?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $base_assets; ?>js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $base_assets; ?>js/jquery.ccslider.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $sliderOptions;
    var $containerSlider = $('#home-animation');

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if( !document.createElement('canvas').getContext ) {
            //If no canvas is created it shows the 2d slider.
             sliderOptions = {effectType: '2d', animSpeed: 2500};
        } else {
             //Otherwise, it goes 3d! *-* YEY
             sliderOptions = {effectType: '3d', animSpeed: 2500};
        }
        $($containerSlider).ccslider(sliderOptions);
    });
</script>
```

So, i think that it's alright.

Before you ask, $base_assets ir correct and there are no 404 errors on any of the scripts.
By the way, i'm using CodeIgniter on this one. So.... anyone able to light things a bit for me?

Thanks in advance, Jorge Ferrari.

Comment: Have you tried changing `$($containerSlider).ccslider(sliderOptions);` to `$containerSlider.ccslider(sliderOptions);`

Comment: $('#home-animation').ccslider();
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ccslider'

Comment: Try doing `alert(!!(jQuery.fn.ccslider))`, if ccslider is loaded, it will output true

Comment: It output false, what can be the problem?

Comment: It's not loading for some reason. Are you absolutely sure you followed the instructions for including it in your webpage?

Comment: Also try getting the latest version of jQuery

Comment: And set up a demo page so I can try to get it working.